# Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012 R2 run time issue

Tags: .net, printing, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I want to make some changes in receipt. I have a test machine with drawer, printer etc. So i can test printing receipt.
But I get 2 errors when try to print receipt. And warning on Ax window "Could not print the receipt. Do you want to try printing again ?" These are error's description below:

> 1. error
>
> LSRetailPosis.TransactionServices.EstablishConnection:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)    at
>   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean
>   includeIPv6)    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String
>   hostNameOrAddress)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.DnsCache.Resolve(Uri uri).
>
> 2. error
>
> LSRetailPosis.TransactionServices.EstablishConnection:
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: No DNS entries exist
>   for host axpos_dev. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such
>   host is known    at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)    at
>   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean
>   includeIPv6)    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String
>   hostNameOrAddress)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.DnsCache.Resolve(Uri uri)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.DnsCache.Resolve(Uri uri)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.GetIPAddresses(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri
>   uri, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri
>   uri, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedFramingRequestChannel.StreamedFramingRequest.SendRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation
>   operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken
>   currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel
>   channel, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.Dynamics.Retail.TransactionServices.ClientProxy.ITransactionService.IsAlive()
>   at LSRetailPosis.TransactionServices.CheckConnection().

I tested printer with test software and it works just fine. How can i work out this problem ?

Comment: I presume that you can actually see/resolve/ping the host mentioned - 'axpos_dev' from the machine that you are working on... And the report server can see it as well.

Comment: Yes that's right I can do any process except printing receipt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can print other reports. So deploying reports in AX2012 R2/R3 is really a pain. Did you try following?

- Clear caches - Tools -> Caches -> Refresh Report Server
- Restart AOS and Report Server
- Do you have local Administration rights on the Report Server? (You need them to deploy a Report)
- Rebuild CIL?
- Do you deploy the Report out of Visual Studio or from AX?
- Do you have more the one Report Service running on the Server?
- Refresh the configuration out of the Microsoft Dynamics AX Configuration Utility
- And last one. What kind of modification have you done?

Comment: I foun out print problem. I was using standart A4 paper and printer couldn't print when i change with thermal receipt paper it worked ! And this error is independant from print issue. I keep taking these 2 errors when i run project and making transactions but axpos working fine. Sorry for misguided you I am newbie in AX :(